# Draw an arc around a rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw something like this:

[image: Arc Around a rectangle]

Is there any way I can achieve this using Tikz? So far, I have drawn:

[image: Arc Inside a rectangle]

using the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=1.5pt}]
    \node (A) at (-5,3) {};
    \node (B) at (-2,3) {};
    \node (C) at (-5,0) {};
    \node (D) at (-2,0) {};
    \node (E) at (2,3) {};
    \node (F) at (5,3) {};
    \node (G) at (2,0) {};
    \node (H) at (5,0) {};
\end{scope}
    \draw[->] (-1.5,1.5) -- (1.5,1.5);
\begin{scope}[-]
    \path
        (A) edge (B)
        (B) edge (D)
        (D) edge (C)
        (C) edge (A)
        (A) edge (D)
        (C) edge (B)
        (E) edge (F)
        (F) edge (H)
        (H) edge (G)
        (G) edge (E)
        (E) edge (H)
        (F) edge[bend left] (G);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I added the part that seemed relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `to path` library (section 70 in pgfmanual) options like `in`, `out` angles and `looseness` to adjust the path.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=1.5pt}]
    \node (A) at (-5,3) {};
    \node (B) at (-2,3) {};
    \node (C) at (-5,0) {};
    \node (D) at (-2,0) {};
    \node (E) at (2,3) {};
    \node (F) at (5,3) {};
    \node (G) at (2,0) {};
    \node (H) at (5,0) {};
\end{scope}
    \draw[->] (-1.5,1.5) -- (1.5,1.5);
\begin{scope}[-]
    \path
        (A) edge (B)
        (B) edge (D)
        (D) edge (C)
        (C) edge (A)
        (A) edge (D)
        (C) edge (B)
        (E) edge (F)
        (F) edge (H)
        (H) edge (G)
        (G) edge (E)
        (E) edge (H)
        (G) edge[out=330,in=-60, looseness=2] (F);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what if I wanted to draw it the other way around?

Comment: `(F) edge[bend left=90,looseness=2] (G)` is maybe simpler and the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution using `tikz arc` function or `controls` F

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={coordinate}]
  \draw (0,0)node(a) {} -- ++(2,0) node(b) {} -- ++(0,2) node(c) {} -- ++(-2,0) node(d) {} -- cycle;
  \draw (d) -- (b);
  \draw (a) arc (-135:45:{sqrt(2)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={coordinate}]
  \draw (0,0)node(a) {} -- ++(2,0) node(b) {} -- ++(0,2) node(c) {} -- ++(-2,0) node(d) {} -- cycle;
  \draw (d) -- (b);
  \draw[rotate=-45] (a) arc (-90:90:2 and {sqrt(2)});
  \draw[dashed,blue] ($(d)!.5!(b)$) -- ++(-45:2) node[sloped,above=-2pt,font=\tiny,rectangle,midway] {2cm};
  \draw[dashed,blue] ($(d)!.5!(b)$) -- ++(-135:{sqrt(2)}) node[sloped,above=-2pt,font=\tiny,rectangle,midway] {sqrt(2)cm};
  \draw[dashed] ($(d)!.5!(b)$) node(x) {} -- ++(-90:.8) node[font=\tiny,rectangle,near end,left,red] {$45^\circ$};
  \draw[red] ($(x)+(-135:.5)$) arc (-135:-90:.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={coordinate}]
  \draw (0,0)node(a) {} -- ++(2,0) node(b) {} -- ++(0,2) node(c) {} -- ++(-2,0) node(d) {} -- cycle;
  \draw (d) -- (b);
  \draw (a) .. controls ++(-35:2.5) and ++(-55:2.5) .. (c);
  \draw[blue,dashed] (a) -- ++(-35:2.5) node[sloped,below=-2pt,font=\tiny,rectangle,midway]  {2.5cm} node[at end](ac) {};
  \draw[blue,dashed] (c) -- ++(-55:2.5) node[sloped,above=-2pt,font=\tiny,rectangle,midway]  {2.5cm} node[at end](cc) {};
  \draw[blue,dashed] (c) -- ++(0:1) node[font=\tiny,rectangle,near end,below,red] {$55^\circ$};
  \draw[blue,dashed] (a) -- ++(0:1) node[font=\tiny,rectangle,near end,below,red] {$35^\circ$};
  \draw[red] ($(c)+(.5,0)$) arc (0:-55:.5);
  \draw[red] ($(a)+(.5,0)$) arc (0:-35:.5);
  \draw[blue,fill] (ac) circle (1pt);
  \draw[blue,fill] (cc) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

The results look like this

[image: new_tikz_arc_drawings]